# User defined function with mutate and case_when in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to know if/how can I turn the call bellow into a function that can be used in a task that I do fairly often with my data. Sadly, I can't figure out how to design function from the call that involves `mutate`, and `case_when`, both of these functions rely on `dplyr` package and require number of additional arguments.

Alternatively, the call itself seems redundant to me with so many `case_when`, perhaps it's possible to reduce how many times its used.

Any help and information about alternative approaches is welcomed.

The call looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

test_data %>%
  mutate(
    multipleoptions_o1 = case_when(
      str_detect(multipleoptions, "option1") ~ 1,
      is.na(multipleoptions) ~ NA_real_,
      TRUE ~ 0),
    multipleoptions_o2 = case_when(
      str_detect(multipleoptions, "option2") ~ 1,
      is.na(multipleoptions) ~ NA_real_,
      TRUE ~ 0),
    multipleoptions_o3 = case_when(
      str_detect(multipleoptions, "option3") ~ 1,
      is.na(multipleoptions) ~ NA_real_,
      TRUE ~ 0),
    multipleoptions_o4 = case_when(
      str_detect(multipleoptions, "option4") ~ 1,
      is.na(multipleoptions) ~ NA_real_,
      TRUE ~ 0)
  )
```

Sample data:

```
structure(list(multipleoptions = c("option1", "option2", "option3", 
NA, "option2,option3", "option4")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Desired output of the function:

```
structure(list(multipleoptions = c("option1", "option2", "option3", 
NA, "option2,option3", "option4"), multipleoptions_o1 = c(1, 
0, 0, NA, 0, 0), multipleoptions_o2 = c(0, 1, 0, NA, 1, 0), multipleoptions_o3 = c(0, 
0, 1, NA, 1, 0), multipleoptions_o4 = c(0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Arguments of the function should probably be: `data` (i.e., input dataset), `multipleoptions` (i.e., the column from data containing answer options, always one column),  `patterns_to_look_for` (i.e., str_detect patterns to look up in the multipleoptions), `number_of_options`, ideally the number of options can be more or less than 4, (I am not sure if it's achievable), `output_columns` (i.e., names of new columns, it's always name or original column followed by the option number or option name).

Comment: Which parts of the function call need to be arguments? (i.e. will change when used on different data)

Comment: @CalumYou I've listed out arguments that I see likely to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid the lengthy `case_when` code by splitting the options into separate elements, taking advantage of nesting/unnesting to get a single column of options, and then spreading to get a separate column for each option.

**Updated Answer**

```
library(tidyverse)

# Arguments
# data     A data frame
# patterns Regular expression giving the pattern(s) at which to split the options strings
# ...      Grouping columns, the first of which must be the "options" column.
#           If options has repeated values, then there must be a second grouping 
#           column (an "ID" column) to differentiate these repeated values.
fnc = function(data, patterns, ...) {
  col = quos(...)

  data %>% 
    mutate(option=str_split(!!!col[[1]], patterns)) %>% 
    unnest %>% 
    mutate(value=1) %>% 
    group_by(!!!col) %>% 
    mutate(num_chosen = ifelse(is.na(!!!col[[1]]), 0, sum(value))) %>% 
    spread(option, value, fill=0) %>%
    select_at(vars(-matches("NA")))
}

fnc(test_data, ",", multipleoptions)
```

> ```
>   multipleoptions num_chosen option1 option2 option3 option4
> 1         option1          1       1       0       0       0
> 2         option2          1       0       1       0       0
> 3 option2,option3          2       0       1       1       0
> 4         option3          1       0       0       1       0
> 5         option4          1       0       0       0       1
> 6            <NA>          0       0       0       0       0
> ```

```
# Fake data
ops = paste0("option",1:4)

set.seed(2)
d = data_frame(var=replicate(20, paste(sample(ops, sample(1:4,1, prob=c(10,8,5,1))), collapse=","))) 
# Add missing values
d = bind_rows(d[1:5,], data.frame(var=rep(NA,3)), d[6:nrow(d),])

fnc(d %>% mutate(ID=1:n()), ",", var, ID)
```

> ```
>                                var ID num_chosen option1 option2 option3 option4
> 1                          option1 17          1       1       0       0       0
> 2                  option1,option2 12          2       1       1       0       0
> 3          option1,option2,option3  5          3       1       1       1       0
> 4  option1,option2,option4,option3  9          4       1       1       1       1
> 5                  option1,option3  2          2       1       0       1       0
> 6          option1,option3,option4  3          3       1       0       1       1
> 7          option1,option4,option2 20          3       1       1       0       1
> 8  option1,option4,option3,option2 13          4       1       1       1       1
> 9                          option2 11          1       0       1       0       0
> 10                 option2,option3 23          2       0       1       1       0
> 11         option2,option3,option4 21          3       0       1       1       1
> 12                         option3  1          1       0       0       1       0
> 13                         option3 15          1       0       0       1       0
> 14                 option3,option1  4          2       1       0       1       0
> 15         option3,option2,option4 14          3       0       1       1       1
> 16 option3,option4,option2,option1 22          4       1       1       1       1
> 17                         option4 10          1       0       0       0       1
> 18                         option4 16          1       0       0       0       1
> 19                         option4 18          1       0       0       0       1
> 20         option4,option2,option3 19          3       0       1       1       1
> 21                            <NA>  6          0       0       0       0       0
> 22                            <NA>  7          0       0       0       0       0
> 23                            <NA>  8          0       0       0       0       0
> ```

**Original Answer**

```
test_data %>% 
  filter(!is.na(multipleoptions)) %>% 
  mutate(option=str_split(multipleoptions, ",")) %>% 
  unnest %>% 
  mutate(value=1) %>% 
  spread(option, value)
```

> ```
>   multipleoptions option1 option2 option3 option4
>   <chr>             <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
> 1 option1               1      NA      NA      NA
> 2 option2              NA       1      NA      NA
> 3 option2,option3      NA       1       1      NA
> 4 option3              NA      NA       1      NA
> 5 option4              NA      NA      NA       1
> ```

Packaging this into a function:

```
fnc = function(data, col, patterns) {
  col = enquo(col)

  data %>% 
    filter(!is.na(!!col)) %>% 
    mutate(option=str_split(!!col, patterns)) %>% 
    unnest %>% 
    mutate(value=1) %>% 
    spread(option, value)
}


fnc(test_data, multipleoptions, ",")
```

If your real data has more than one row with the same value of `multipleoptons`, then this code will work only if there's also an `ID` column that distinguishes different rows with the same value of `multipleoptions`. For example:

```
# Fake data
ops = paste0("option",1:4)

set.seed(2)
d = data.frame(var=replicate(20, paste(sample(ops, sample(1:4,1, prob=c(10,8,5,1))), collapse=",")))

fnc(d, var, ",")
```

> Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 27), (16, 28, 30)

```
# Add unique row identifier
fnc(d %>% mutate(ID = 1:n()), var, ",")
```

> ```
>                                var ID option1 option2 option3 option4
> 1                          option1 14       1      NA      NA      NA
> 2                  option1,option2  9       1       1      NA      NA
> 3          option1,option2,option3  5       1       1       1      NA
> 4  option1,option2,option4,option3  6       1       1       1       1
> 5                  option1,option3  2       1      NA       1      NA
> 6          option1,option3,option4  3       1      NA       1       1
> 7          option1,option4,option2 17       1       1      NA       1
> 8  option1,option4,option3,option2 10       1       1       1       1
> 9                          option2  8      NA       1      NA      NA
> 10                 option2,option3 20      NA       1       1      NA
> 11         option2,option3,option4 18      NA       1       1       1
> 12                         option3  1      NA      NA       1      NA
> 13                         option3 12      NA      NA       1      NA
> 14                 option3,option1  4       1      NA       1      NA
> 15         option3,option2,option4 11      NA       1       1       1
> 16 option3,option4,option2,option1 19       1       1       1       1
> 17                         option4  7      NA      NA      NA       1
> 18                         option4 13      NA      NA      NA       1
> 19                         option4 15      NA      NA      NA       1
> 20         option4,option2,option3 16      NA       1       1       1
> ```

Comment: Thank you. `fnc(t1, routine_provided_target, ",")` does close to what I need. What I am missing from your function is that my output gives NA only when a person did not select any option at all (i.e., row 4 of my output) but will give 0 to person who selected one option but left out others empty. For example, your output, row 1 should be 1/0/0/0 not 1/NA/NA/NA. This way I can differentiate "true" NA from someone simply not choosing an option.

Comment: See updated answer. It assigns 0 to any option not chosen and 1 to each chosen option, including cases where the subject did not choose any option, and adds in a `num_chosen` column tallying the number of options chosen.

Comment: Thank you. This works very well and does the job. Accepted it as the answer. On a side note, I've also added:
`option = str_remove_all(option, " "),
option = str_trunc(option, 6, "right", ellipsis = ""),
option = paste0(new_col, "_", option))` to the parentheses of your `mutate(value=1)`. It's to make sure the new column names are not spurious if they contain spaces, truncates them, and also adds `new_col` as a parameter to specify the prefix of newly created columns.